# java.io.FileNotFoundException: I:\FTP 23-04-2017 (Acceso denegado) / (Access denied)

Tags: java, ftp

Good morning to the whole community. I tell you a little;
I have had a problem with a small application that wanted to make me to make automatic backups from a server to my computer. (I know there are similar APPS to do it, but I want to do it myself). The error I get basically is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: I:\FTP 23-04-2017 (Acceso denegado)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at com.cristianvalero.ftp.download.FTPDownload.downloadFile(FTPDownload.java:91)
at tester.main(tester.java:39)
```

Main tester class:

```
public class tester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    FTPDownload ftpDownload = new FTPDownload("127.0.0.1", 21, "root", "123");
    ftpDownload.conect();
    if (ftpDownload.isConnected())
    {
        ftpDownload.downloadFile("eula.txt", null);
    }
  }
}
```

FTPDownload class:

```
public class FTPDownload
{
  private String server;
  private int port;
  private String user;
  private String passwd;
  private FTPClient ftpClient;

public FTPDownload(String server, int port, String user, String passwd)
{
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
    this.user = user;
    this.passwd = passwd;
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
}

public void conect()
{
    try
    {
        ftpClient.connect(this.server, this.port);
        ftpClient.login(this.user, this.passwd);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        System.out.println("[FTP] Successfully connected.");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        catchPrinting(e);
    }
}

public boolean isConnected()
{
    return ftpClient.isConnected();
}

public boolean downloadFile(String remotePath, String optionalPathSaveDownloaded)
{
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    boolean success = false;

    if (optionalPathSaveDownloaded == null)
    {
        System.out.println("[FTP] Setting default saved files on desktop because downlaod path is null...");
        optionalPathSaveDownloaded = "I:/FTP "+dtf.format(localDate)+"/";
        createFolder(optionalPathSaveDownloaded);
        //optionalPathSaveDownloaded = "C://Users//"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"//Desktop//FTP//";
    }

    try
    {
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(optionalPathSaveDownloaded));
        success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remotePath, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success)
        {
            System.out.println("[FTP] File downlaoded successfully.");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        catchPrinting(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        catchPrinting(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected())
            {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return success;
}

private void catchPrinting(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("[FTP] ¡OPS! An internal error has ocurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
}

private void createFolder(String folderPath)
{
    File f = new File(folderPath);
    if (!f.exists())
    {
        f.mkdir();
    }
}
}
```

> The drive "I:" is simply a partition I have from a disk totally different to "C:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you provide to the `FileOutputStream` contructor has to be a path to a *file* to write to, not a path to a *folder*. How would it know a name of a file to create?

```
optionalPathSaveDownloaded = "I:/FTP "+dtf.format(localDate)+"/"+"somefilename.ext";
```

Comment: It's totally true. Thank you very much, buddy!